# Query for Sum(total)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

`exchanges` table structure:

```
  id   exchange       created_at            updated_at        deleted_at   start_time   close_time  
 ---- ---------- --------------------- --------------------- ------------ ------------ ------------ 
   1   NSE        2018-04-18 06:22:11   2018-04-18 06:22:11   (NULL)       09:15:00     03:30:00    
   2   BSE        2018-05-06 07:07:53   2018-05-06 07:07:53   (NULL)       00:00:00     00:00:00    
   3   NYSE       2018-05-19 08:34:07   2018-05-19 08:34:07   (NULL)       00:00:00     00:00:00
```

`finaltrades` table structure:

```
  id   user_id   exchange_id   market_id   symbol_id      buy_datetime          sell_datetime      buy_rate   sell_rate   quantities  
 ---- --------- ------------- ----------- ----------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------- ----------- ------------ 
   1         1             1           1          96   2018-05-25 18:13:26   0000-00-00 00:00:00       2205           0          100  
   2         1             1           1          96   0000-00-00 00:00:00   2018-05-25 18:13:59          0        6680          100  
   3         4             1           1          23   2018-05-25 18:16:27   0000-00-00 00:00:00          0           0           10  
   4         1             1           1          96   2018-05-25 18:13:59   0000-00-00 00:00:00      50351           0           30  
   5         1             1           1          15   0000-00-00 00:00:00   2018-05-25 18:34:46          0         100          150  
   6         4             1           1         573   2018-05-26 09:29:17   2018-05-27 03:10:09         10          10           10  
   7         1             1           1          15   2018-05-11 09:30:54   2018-05-25 18:34:56         40         100           40
```

---

**I want to subtract `buy_datetime - sell_datetime = hours`, apply that calculation to all rows and add all the results together.**

For example,

```
buy_datetime - sell_datetime = 12 hours
buy_datetime - sell_datetime = 19 hours
buy_datetime - sell_datetime = 11 hours
```

now

```
total all = 32 hours
```

here is what I came up with so far

```js
public function total_hours_count {

    $first_hour_trade = DB::table('finaltrade')            
                                 ->select('finaltrade.*')               
                                 ->where('buy_datetime','-','sell_datetime')
                                 ->sum() -> get();
            
    return response() -> json($first_hour_trade);
}
```

I don't know where the mistake in the code is.

Comment: There is no minus in where clauses. You need to define $buy_time and $sell_time, after that use regular minus calculation with carbon.

Comment: Actually, I am not familiar with query, therefore first, i have to understand Carbon. @AliÖzen . As per your answer, I should store all $buy_dateime in variable, later I have to minus it with another variable $sell_time.

Comment: Can you write a query in regular MySQL?

Comment: No, I am not but i am learning concept of Mysql. @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum up the difference of buy_datetime and sell_datetime from whole table you could use raw expressions

```
DB::table('finaltrade')
    ->select(DB::raw("SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(buy_datetime, sell_datetime )) / 3600) AS total_hours")
    ->get();
```

Comment: This code is working perfectly what i want. Where can I find these methods like, `SUM, TIME_TO_SEC, TIMEDIFF`  etc. I think you should refer these all in my brain.

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati see this [MySQL function reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_mysql.asp) and don't forget to [mark helpful answers as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I'm unable to mark helpful answered, ERROR "15 reputation". @ThomasFlinkow